# "The source of the report definition has not been specified"

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to pass two parameters with the input from two dropdown list from a .aspx page. in an rdlc report but in code behind it show an error.

Here is my code Below in.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class RDLC : System.Web.UI.Page

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
     fillcontrols();
    }
  }

  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    try
    {
      ReportViewer1.Reset();
      ReportDataSource rptsrc = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", GetData());
      ReportParameter rp1 = new ReportParameter("Month", ddlMonth.SelectedValue.ToString());
      ReportParameter rp2 = new ReportParameter("Year", ddlYear.SelectedValue.ToString());
      ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { rp1, rp2 });
      ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rptsrc);
      ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Report.rdlc";
      ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
    }
    catch(Exception ex) 
    { }
  }

  public void fillcontrols()
  {
    ddlMonth.Items.Clear();
    ddlMonth.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
    ddlMonth.Items.Add(new ListItem("Select Month", "-1"));
    int nMonth = DateTime.Now.Month;
    for (int j = nMonth; j <= nMonth + 10; j++)
    {
      ddlMonth.Items.Add(new ListItem(j.ToString(),j.ToString()));
    }

    ddlMonth.SelectedValue = "-1";

    ddlYear.Items.Clear();
    ddlYear.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
    ddlYear.Items.Add(new ListItem("Select Year", "-1"));
    int nYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
    for (int i = nYear-3; i <= nYear + 3; i++)
    {
      ddlYear.Items.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString()));
    }

    ddlYear.SelectedValue = "-1";
  }

  private DataTable GetData()
  {
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string conString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProjectManagementConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from ProjectBilling",con);
      SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
      da.Fill(dt);
    }
    return dt;
  }
}
```

Comment: ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();   ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rptsrc);

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Specify the report path and then add the datasource.

```
 try
{
 ReportViewer1.Reset();
 ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
 ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
 ReportDataSource rptsrc = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", GetData());
 ReportParameter rp1 = new ReportParameter("Month", ddlMonth.SelectedValue.ToString());
 ReportParameter rp2 = new ReportParameter("Year", ddlYear.SelectedValue.ToString());
 ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Report.rdlc";
 ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rptsrc);
 ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { rp1, rp2 }) ;
 ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
}
catch(Exception ex) 
{ }
```

Comment: it shows the report but does not show the report according to the parameters @Kumar

Comment: @star_tasneem: Check the parameter name(`Month` and `Year`)  are same in report and code

Comment: i catch the problem in Getdata() the query is for selecting all data from ProjectBilling table..what would be the search query?@kumar

Comment: problem solved..u r a rockstar buddy..keep up the good work @kumar